# Which keychain should I install my iOS Developer certificate in?

Tags: ios, certificate, visual-studio-mac

I have generated and downloaded an iOS Development certificate.  I double clicked the file, as instructed.

[image: Screenshot]

Which keychain should I install it in?

I get `An error occurred. Unable to import "iphone Developer:...".  Error -25294` if I select the default `Local Items` keychain.

I tried installing in the other keychains but I still get error `Error: No valid iOS code signing keys found in keychain. You need to request a codesigning certificate from https://developer.apple.com.`

Comment: Hey sir, did you figure this one out? Going through the same exact hurdle.

Comment: @DanielBirowskyPopeski there were multiple issues with my Apple Developer setup/provisioning profile.  I don't know what I did to fix it, but had to check everything.